# Problem in login page using form based authentication

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication

I want a login page in which  if any user types invalid password or username after clicking submit button, then the user will be displayed an error message on the same page.

What should I have to make this requirement enable? Is this possible with ajax or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with Ajax. It's easiest, frankly, if you use a library like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), etc., because they smooth out browser differences and such for you, and have a lot of built-in functionality.

For example, here's a fairly succinct way you can submit a form and look at the response using Ajax with Prototype:

```
$('formid').request({
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        // Request succeeded, check result for whether login was valid
    }
});
```

(That assumes the form has the id "formid".)

Here's a more complete example, which also shows how you hook into the submission process. You might trigger that code by hooking the `submit` event on the form and sending the Ajax request instead:

```
$('formid').observe('submit', function(event) {
    // Prevent the standard form submission
    event.stop();

    // Do it via Ajax instead, including an additional flag telling
    // the server that this is an Ajax call
    this.request({
        parameters: {viaAjax: true},
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            // Request succeeded, check result for whether login was valid
            if (response.responseJSON &&
                response.responseJSON.loginOkay) {
                // Login worked!
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The above does these things:

1. Hooks up a Javascript handler for when the user submits the form
2. Handles that event by cancelling the usual form submission and sending an Ajax call instead
3. Along with the form data, we also include a `viaAjax` flag telling the server that we're sending the form via Ajax

The server should expect the form to arrive either with or without the `viaAjax` flag. If the flag is there, it means the browser supports Javascript and the form was submitted that way, and so it should just return a flag telling us whether the login was okay (in the above I've assumed it will return [JSON](http://json.org)-formatted data `{"loginOkay": true}`, which means it should set the content type to `application/json`). If the flag **isn't** there, Javascript is disabled on the browser and the server should handle the form submission in the normal way, returning a full HTML page. (This business of handling it regardless of whether Javascript is enabled is called "progressive enhancement" or "graceful degradation".)